# getAttachmentsAsync() return different IDs when it is call is JS and in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-app

I am working on an outlook web add-in that gets attachments. But I found out that's API returns different ID for JS and in backend(C#)

In JS when I call `Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync()` it is return this ID:
`AAMkADhlZGM3ZDRiLTc3ODEtNGRhZi05NDNhLWFiMWNkOTc1YWNkZQBGAAAAAAAvp5uuw9HTToIFsfv180ZsBwCYtBG78gMyRLPMDVxMNy4UAAAAAAEPAACYtBG78gMyRLPMDVxMNy4UAAHoiefYAAABEgAQAEK4dcJBHC5Hso8DtB+2NaQ=`

In C#

```
var graph = new GraphServiceClient(url, authToken);
var request = graph.Me.Messages[itemId].Attachments.Request();
var attachments = await request.GetAsync();
```

this code return this ID
`AAMkADhlZGM3ZDRiLTc3ODEtNGRhZi05NDNhLWFiMWNkOTc1YWNkZQBGAAAAAAAvp5uuw9HTToIFsfv180ZsBwCYtBG78gMyRLPMDVxMNy4UAAAAAAEPAACYtBG78gMyRLPMDVxMNy4UAAHoiefYAAABEgAQAEK4dcJBHC5Hso8DtB_2NaQ=`

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: That's just two different variants of base64 encoding.  The original used +.  The URL-safe variant uses - instead.  Compare RFC 2045 to RFC 3458.

Comment: That doesn't completely explain your difference.  The + should have become -, not _.  You're sure you pasted it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for answer Tom. Yes, I am sure that this is the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#convertToRestId_itemId__restVersion_) to convert an item ID formatted for EWS into REST format.

[Get Item ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api#get-the-item-id)